# Remove item from Object set that doesn't exist in query set

Tags: python

`Ordered` returns a subset of `unordered_groups`...

`Items` sorts `unordered groups` based on `ordered`. I am trying to figure out how to remove any items within `items` that do not exist in `ordered` but am having trouble figuring out where to start.

```
unordered_groups = connect().get_delivery_groups_for_season(self.division_id, self.id)
ordered = DeliveryGroupOrder.objects.filter(season=self.name.get('en'), visibility="1")
order_by_name = dict(ordered.values_list('deliverygroup', 'order'))
items = sorted(unordered_groups, key=lambda g: order_by_name.get(g.name.get('en')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saying, this isn't necessarily a [django](/questions/tagged/django) question, it just requires a simple list comprehension.

Lets take blank list `a` to represent `items`, and `b` to represent `ordered`.

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [] #Note: Do not do a = b = [], it will assign a and b to a list with the same ID
>>>
```

Then, let's populate it:

```
>>> import random
>>> a = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)]
>>> b = [random.randint(1, 10) for i in range(10)]
>>> a
[3, 10, 6, 9, 6, 8, 9, 10, 6, 1]
>>> b
[3, 1, 2, 6, 3, 10, 2, 2, 4, 9]
>>>
```

Now, using a simple list comprehension, we can remove the items in `a` that do not exist in `b`:

```
>>> a = [item for item in a if item in b]
>>> a
[3, 10, 6, 9, 6, 9, 10, 6, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess my issue is that `ordered` is a query set. So I will first need to convert it to a list then?

Comment: Yes, you will, otherwise you will not be able to access it the way you access normal lists.